# How to only show bookmark number for the chapters

Tags: bookmarks

I am using the `bookmark` package to make the output pdf bookmarked, here is the thing that I want to show the bookmark number for the chapters but only show the sections' title, I have googled it but no proper result came up, how can I do this?

```
% this is what I am using for bookmarking.
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is an automatic interface. One would have to patch some commands. But manually it is easy:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[numbered,depth=section]{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\bookmarksetup{numbered=false}
\section{Foobar}
\subsection{FooFoobar}

\bookmarksetup{numbered}
\chapter{Foo 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]